# jQuery change event on the iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, events

I have a problem getting this to fire on iPhone 4, any ideas?

```
$('select').change(function () {
    alert('you changed this');
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
$('select').live('change',function () {
    alert('you changed this');
});
```

Comment: 4min for you to get your tick :)

Comment: So what's the reason for this? They select is on the page and doesn't get added dynamically so it should have fired just with .change?!!

Comment: I haven't worked with jQuery Mobile, but from what I understand when you touch a select box the resulting menu is actually a totally different UI control.. perhaps the "change" event is captured by this new control, so you need to use the live() function. Just a theory...

Comment: I like your theory it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('select').bind('change',function () {
    alert('you changed this');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery mobile, you might want to check this out https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1163

Comment: I am using jqTouch but I guess they would be a bit similar. Thanks for this