# Change event not firing on select elements with Mobile Safari "form assistant"

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I have dynamic select drop-down menus. For example, if you select a specific month, the 2nd select element will populate with number of days in that month.

This works as intended, however when the user is on an iPhone and uses the "Next" button built into Mobile Safari's "form assistant", the `change` event (using jQuery) doesn't appear to fire and the 2nd select does not update.

```
$('.month').change(function() {
    // update "days" select element
});
```

FYI I'm also using jQuery mobile

Comment: any output in the iPhone debugger (Safari debug mode)?

Comment: None. I'm thinking this may just be a mobile safari bug.

Comment: Safari doesnt handle all the standard events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best work-around I could find was based on this post...

[Strange behavior of select/dropdown's onchange() JS event when using 'Next' on Mobile Safari Dropdown list item select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960731/strange-behavior-of-select-dropdowns-onchange-js-event-when-using-next-on-m)

Using the plugin (from the link above), I had to force the select menu to `blur` as soon as an option was chosen with Mobile Safari's "form assistant".

I noticed however when brute force testing these menus an extra `blur` event would fire after a few back-and-forth selections. An extra `focus` seemed to fix that.

```
$('select').quickChange(function () {
    $(this).blur();
    $('select').focus(); // somehow prevents an extra blur from firing on focus
});
```

With a separate `change` function I am updating the second select menu dynamically.

```
$("#select-choice-month").change(function () {
    // update second select dynamically
});
```

*Only tested on Mobile Safari / iOS 5.0.1 thus far.

Answer (score 7):

You could also bind some additional events like `blur` ( don't know if blur does fire on iphone though)

```
$('.month').bind('change blur',function(){

});
```

or have you tried:

```
$('.month').live('change',function(){
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried several different events as I thought that might be the issue. Was not able to get any to fire.

Comment: The month select is static in the DOM so the `live()` function I don't believe is necessary. I gave it a shot anyhow and no luck.

Comment: @wdm hm too bad. I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431611/jquery-change-event-on-the-iphone/6431657#6431657