# click option in select by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Whenever an option in the select is clicked, I need to call an ajax with
`$("#myselect option").click(hanler)` event handler.But this feature is not working in Safari Browser

ex:

```
$("#myselect option").click(function(){
    // call ajax
})
```

Comment: Just `$("#myselect").change(function(){
// call ajax
});`

Comment: I want when the user reselect the option it still called the ajax. Change() only when have change in option.

Comment: create a custom dropdown using divs coz what youre looking for is not possible with the default dropdowns

Answer (score 3):

Try using change() while selecting option from select.

```
$("#myselect option").on("change",function(){
// call ajax
});
```

Comment: if value is selected, i select it again, change() not effect.

Comment: You can set a blank option at first. Then you can select other option.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the answer already written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680992/change-event-not-firing-on-select-elements-with-mobile-safari-form-assistant). Give a try by adding an extra event like blur();

```
$('select').quickChange(function () {
  $(this).blur();
  $('select').focus(); // somehow prevents an extra blur from firing   on focus
});


$("#select-choice-month").change(function () {
  // update second select dynamically
});
```

Hope it will give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks, i will check it now.

Comment: Yes! Give a try and check. It should work & accept my answer the right one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, I tested it on a safari of ipad, it does not run as expected

Comment: Have you checked these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680992/change-event-not-firing-on-select-elements-with-mobile-safari-form-assistant

Comment: and also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960731/strange-behavior-of-select-dropdowns-onchange-js-event-when-using-next-on-m

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `change` event rather than click event, also bind the code inside `$(document).ready`. Please try the sample code and verify whether this fits for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select#myselect").change(function () {
                console.log("You have selected " + $("select#myselect").val());
                //Call your ajax here.
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="myselect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Example, i open select_box and  select value 1, chage() effect, now, i open select_box and select value 1, change() not effect.
change () only works when the option changed.

Comment: The main problem is that there is no click event for option. Either you can add click event for select that will trigger even you just click on select dropdown itself, or you can go for change event that will trigger only if the selected option changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "change" event on the select tag, not the options themself.

```
$('#myselect').on('change', function (e) {
    myFunction();
});
```

Everytime, you change the current value of your select, "myfunction' will be call.